# If parent has class add class to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a class to an `img` element (for an animation) if the parent of 'image-reveal-check' has an active class, how do I do this?

**Clarification: The parent class does not always have 'active', that class is added when the element gets in the viewport.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="active">
    <div class="image-reveal-check">
        <div class="image-reveal-inner">
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($(".image-reveal-check").parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(".image-reveal-inner img").addClass('image-reveal-start');
}
```

Comment: why you don't simply apply the CSS of that class considering the parent class? You are overcomplicating an easy thing

Comment: Seems working. Do you have multiple `.image-reveal-check`?

Comment: So what's the problem ? Your jquery code isn't working ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I forgot to add some clarification to the original post, the 'active' class get's added to the parent when it's in the viewport. What I'm trying to do is trigger a class with an animation for the IMG when the parent has the 'active' class

Comment: Where your call this part of code? put your code inside the ready function and recheck...

Comment: this will change nothing ... even if the parent doesn't always have the active class you don't need to add a class to the child element, you need to apply style considering the active class: if active is added the style will be applied if it's removed the style also

Comment: The 'image-reveal-start' has an :after in the CSS containing the animation, when the parent has an 'active' class the 'image-reveal-start' needs to be added to the IMG and then triggers the :after and animation

Comment: all you need is to do this `.active .image-reveal-inner img` .. by they way you shouldn't use after/before with img element

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're right, I was overcomplicating things... this works better! I feel like such an idiot right now. Anyways thanks for the help I'll try this!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one it's working. You can check the output on Code Snippet.**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
if ($(".image-reveal-inner").parent().hasClass('image-reveal-check')) {
 $(".image-reveal-inner img").addClass('image-reveal-start-add');
 console.log( "done!" );
}
});
```

```html
<div class="active">
    <div class="image-reveal-check">
        <div class="image-reveal-inner">
        ASD
            <img alt="img title">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: you should add an explanation so OP understands the problem and solution :)

Comment: The parent class does not always have 'active', that class is added when the element gets in the viewport.

Comment: can you expain the difference between your code and OP code? it see no difference

Comment: I have changed code now please check now it's working fine.

Comment: what have you changed? explain, show us, highlight the difference, etc etc

Comment: In Question "Clarification: The parent class does not always have 'active', that class is added when the element gets in the viewport."

So I have check if parent class = image-reveal-check.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the event explicitly when the `active` class added to the `div`.

Here I've added with a button click, in your case you can do when the element gets added in the viewport.

```js
$("#addClassActive").click(function() { 

//Here on button click the active class is added to div. For your case this needs to be called when the element added to the viewport
    $('.image-reveal-check').parent().addClass('active').trigger('classChange');
});

$('div:eq(0)').on('classChange', function() { //finding the root div and finding img and adding the desired class
     $(this).find("img").addClass("image-reveal-start")
});
```

```css
.image-reveal-start
{
 border: solid 1px red;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="image-reveal-check">
        <div class="image-reveal-inner">
            <img src="#" title="I am Image!" alt="I am Image!" />
            
            <button id="addClassActive">Add Class</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that without the use of JS at all, just add a rule to your CSS code like :

```
div.active .image-reveal-inner img { }
```

The example below shows how the first image with a parent that has `active` class will be animated with the rule and not the second that has no `active` class on the parent `div`.

```css
div.active .image-reveal-inner img {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
    right: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
    right: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
  <div class="image-reveal-check">
    <div class="image-reveal-inner">
      <img alt="img title" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lRQ9.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image-reveal-check">
    <div class="image-reveal-inner">
      <img alt="img title" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lRQ9.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```